# Find the tens and hundreds digits

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility, decimal-expansion

Calculate the digit of the order of tens and hundreds of expansions of:

$7^{100}$ and $11^{2004}$

I don't know a faster method than $7 ^3\equiv 43$ (mod100)  and $11 ^ 2 \equiv 21 $(mod 100), and keep reducing by multiplying until you get the result. I think this method would take a while [mod (100) and (mod 1.000)]

Should this really be laborious?

Comment: Are you familiar with fermat's little theorem?  Does it apply in your situation?  How about Euler's theorem which generalizes fermat's?

Comment: Can you introduce me?

Comment: calculate $7^4$ and $11^{10}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to find a power which is congruent to $1$.

Note that $7^{20}\equiv 1$ mod $1000$ and $11^{50}\equiv 1$ mod $1000$.

Therefore $7^{100}\equiv 1$ mod $1000$.

Can you now find $11^{2004}$?

Comment: How did you find that $11 ^ {50}$ would be congruent with $1 $ mod 1000?

Comment: Did you use Gaussian?

Comment: There are various methods - I'm not sure what you know already. Perhaps the easiest is to find powers of 11 which equal 1 mod 10 (in this case 11 itself does this) then powers of 11 which equal 1 mod 100. These are multiples of 10. So then you only need look at powers of $11^{10}$.

Comment: I don't mind following methods I don't know, anything that slows down work is welcome

Comment: Are you familiar with the Euler function?

Comment: No, but I can search later

Comment: OK - the Euler function of 1000  (see Wikipedia) is 400. Euler's theorem then says that (because 11 and 1000 have no common factors) $11^{400}$  will be congruent to 1 mod 1000. In many questions like this one that would be of great help to you. Notice however that we managed to get an even better answer by a reasonably quick method.

Comment: you can also do a quotient remainder combination on exponents, but it's less than desirable.